# Auto-Mount USB drives when plugged in

Tags: 14.04, usb, automount

I have some old USB-drives that sometimes unmount itself but I don't have the time to replace them by better drives so soon.

How can I configure Ubuntu 14.04 so it automatically re-mounts the external drives and partitions in the same mount-folder so am Mp3 running from that drive continues playing when the drive is back withut having to click on the drive on the left in Nautilus?

Answer (score 0):

Installing usbmount gets better results at mounting things like mp3 players and card readers i have found.

Answer (score 0):

I had a external USB mounted drive that would do the same thing.  Even worse, unplugging it and plugging it back in would not remount it.  And it would not be visible in Nautilus either.

In my case, I would open up a terminal and issue a simple bash command in the directory, to kind of keep it "alive" and busy.

```
$ while [ 1 == 1 ]; do sleep 1; ls; done
```

Just make sure to do that command from inside of a directory on the external drive.  Also you can configure the sleep time to a longer value.  I just put '1' above so you could see it was working.

Comment: Did you ever try mounting it with `sudo mount -t auto /dev/sdXX ~/some-dir` and viewing it there in Nautilus?